# Javascript canvas "game". Hero mooves only one time

Tags: javascript, canvas

Im trying to make simple game in canvas. I made animation for hero using setTimeout() function. I check pressed keys with function moove(e):

Everything works pretty fine when i press leftarrow or rightarrow for the first time, but then hero doesnt moove. Any recomendations to the code is appreciated.

```js
var cns = document.getElementById("can");
cns.height = 600;
cns.width = 300;
var ctx = cns.getContext("2d");
var hero = new Image();
hero.src = "images/hero.png";
hero.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(hero, 120, 570);
  hero.xx = 120;
  hero.yy = 570;
};

var intervalL, intervalR, intervalLL, intervalRR;
var keys = [];

function moove(e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
  if (keys[37]) {
    clearTimeout(intervalR);
    clearTimeout(intervalRR);
    goLeft(hero);
  } else {
    clearTimeout(intervalL);
    clearTimeout(intervalLL);
  }
  if (keys[39]) {
    clearTimeout(intervalL);
    clearTimeout(intervalLL);
    goRight(hero);
  } else {
    clearTimeout(intervalR);
    clearTimeout(intervalRR);
  }
}

function goLeft(img) {
  var x = img.xx,
    y = img.yy;

  function f() {
    ctx.clearRect(img.xx, img.yy, img.width, img.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
    img.xx = x;
    img.yy = y;
    x -= 1.2;
    if (x < -35) {
      x = cns.width;
    }
  }
  if (!intervalL) {
    intervalL = setTimeout(function run() {
      f();
      intervalLL = setTimeout(run, 5);
    }, 5);
  }
}
```

Function goRight is similiar to goLeft.

Function moove is called in tag body onkeydown='moove(event)' onkeyup='moove(event)'.

You can check the project here: https://github.com/Fabulotus/Fabu/tree/master/Canvas%20game%20-%20dodge%20and%20jump

Comment: What calls the `moove` function? It would be helpful to see that in your code example. When do you add values to the `keys` array?

Comment: It is called in body. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work the first time is because the first time through you are setting the position to its previous position (`x = image.xx`) then updating x after you draw. You should update the x value `x -= 1.2` before calling `drawImage`

Comment: This function called every 5ms, so i didnt even notice that, right. I meant, that this code works only when i press right or left arrow for the first time, but when i press it for the second time, hero just stands. I think the problem is that i call same function on keyup and keydown events.

Comment: oh yes, that is true.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "working" version of your code:

```js
var cns = document.getElementById("can");
cns.height = 170;
cns.width = 600;
var ctx = cns.getContext("2d");
var hero = new Image();
hero.src = "http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/api/Image";
hero.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(hero, cns.width-10, cns.height/2);
  hero.xx = cns.width-10;
  hero.yy = cns.height/2;
};

var intervalL, intervalR, intervalLL, intervalRR;
var keys = [];


function goLeft(img) {
  function f() {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cns.width, cns.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, img.xx, img.yy);
    img.xx--;      
    if (img.xx < -img.width) {
      img.xx = cns.width;
    }
  }
  if (!intervalL) {
    intervalL = setTimeout(function run() {
      f();
      intervalLL = setTimeout(run, 5);
    }, 5);
  }
}

goLeft(hero)
```

```html
<canvas id="can">
```

As you can see the `function goLeft` has been significantly simplified.

One recommendation: avoid the many `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` instead use one setInterval to call a draw function that takes care of drawing everything on your game, all the other function should just update the position of your gameObjects.